# Microsoft Word David font parentheses and brackets reversed

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I use Microsoft Office 2016 Pro. For some time now, I have a strange problem where the parentheses come out reversed only when using the Hebrew font "David". Any other font is fine. Also, this issue does not occur in any other text editing software - only Word.

This happens with brackets too.

I must have the David font working properly. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You appear to mistakenly have the English keyboard layout installed.  Now it's been 25 years since I talked to my friend who learned Hebrew as a child, but I seem to recall Hebrew is a Right to Left language but a English is Left to Right.  Since our saying your parentheses are backwards logic dictates they are related

Comment: Can you go into the Fonts options in Windows and find the David font file there, open it and see which version it is? You may have installed some older or not original version.

Comment: Ramhound, I need both layouts. Yisroel, the version was blank but there WERE other third party David fonts installed. I uninstalled all DAVID named fonts, downloaded and installed the original David font, restarted computer and all seems ok now. If you re-post your comment as an answer, I can accept it as a correct answer since it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yisroel wrote, I uninstalled all DAVID named fonts, downloaded and installed the original David font, restarted computer and all seems ok now.